# Copying ranges from different workbooks into one final destination sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm going to be generating some graphs from a lot of data located in multiple workbooks. The data is formatted exactly the same in all workbooks and reside in folders all at the same level. I'm going to be bringing parts (ranges) of the data into one final workbook where I'll generate my graphs from.

I've looked around for examples, and tried Excel help files.

Lots of things seem to be wrong.

Also, how do you add the name of the file that the ranges came from in Column B on the same rows?

```
Sub CopySourceValuesToDestination()

Dim DestPath As String
Dim SourcePath As String
Dim Folder As Variant
Dim Folders As Variant
Dim FileInFolder As Variant
Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Range2 As Range
Dim DesitnationPaste1 As Variant
Dim DesitnationPaste2 As Variant

Folder = Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL")
FileInFolder = Array("ABCFile", "DEFFile", "GHIFile", "JKLFile")

''My final Excel file sits in the parent folder of the source files folders
DestPath = "S:\Common\XYZ\Michael S\Macrotest\"

''Each file has it's own folder, and there are many specific files in each
SourcePath = "S:\Common\XYZ\Michael S\Macrotest\ + Folder"

''Always the same in each of my source files
Range1 = Cells("C4:C8") 
Range2 = Cells("C17:D21") 

''Below I 'm trying to paste Range1 into Column C directly under the last used cell
DestinationPaste1 = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

 ''Below I 'm trying to paste Range2 into Column D directly under the last used cell
DestinationPaste2 = Range("D5000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

''Trying to make it loop through the folder and the_
''files...but this is just a guess
For Each Folder In Folders 
''Again a guess
F = 0 

''The rest of the process would open a source file copy_
''Range1 and then opening the Destination file and pasting_
''it in the Row 1 of Column C. Hopefully it then goes back_
''to the open source file copies Range2 and pastes it the_
''next Row down in Column C

    Workbooks.Open FileName:=SourcePath + FileName + "Source.xls"

        Workbook.Sheet(Sheet2).Range1.Copy

    Workbook.Open FileName:=DestPath + "Destination.xls"

        Workbook.Sheet(Sheet1).DestinationPaste.Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
            Operation:= xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    Windows(SourcePath + FileName + "Source.xls").Activate

        Workbook.Sheet(Sheet2).Range2.Copy

    Workbook.Open FileName:=DestPath + "Destination.xls"

        Workbook.Sheet(Sheet1).DestinationPaste.Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
            xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

  Windows(SourcePath + FileName + "Source.xls").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
F = F + 1
Next

End Sub
```

The outcome of the process would look like the image below but without the colours or the additional "_b":

[image: Column B in the spreadsheet has three letter values like 'ABC' that get repeated. Column C has the same values followed by a number indicating how many times it has appeared. For example, 'ABC1', 'ABC2', 'DEF1', etc.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but I think it will get you closer and give you some clues on how to proceed.  We can edit it to make it right.

```
Sub CopySourceValuesToDestination()

    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim sDestPath As String
    Dim sSourcePath As String
    Dim shDest As Worksheet
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim vaFolder As Variant
    Dim vaFiles As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'array of folder names under sDestPath
    vaFolder = Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL")

    'array of file names under the respective folders in vaFolder
    vaFiles = Array("ABCFile.xls", "DEFFile.xls", "GHIFile.xls", "JKLFile.xls")

    sDestPath = "S:\Common\XYZ\Michael S\Macrotest\"
    sSourcePath = "S:\Common\XYZ\Michael S\Macrotest\"

    'Open the destination workbook at put the destination sheet in a variable
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(sDestPath & "Destination.xls")
    Set shDest = wbDest.Sheets(1)

    'loop through the folders
    For i = LBound(vaFolder) To UBound(vaFolder)
        'open the source
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(sSourcePath & vaFolder(i) & "\" & vaFiles(i))

        'find the next cell in col C
        Set rDest = shDest.Cells(shDest.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        'write the values from source into destination
        rDest.Resize(5, 1).Value = wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("C4:C8").Value

        'repeat for next source range
        Set rDest = shDest.Cells(shDest.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        rDest.Resize(5, 2).Value = wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("C17:D21").Value

        wbSource.Close False
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm about to give this a go. Your comments in the code are much appreciated - using .Value =,  instead of copy & paste is somethign that I'll need to remember for other projects. However, the LBound and UBound part is above me, so I'm off to read about that. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Worked like a charm - and fast! I just amended the second rdest = shDest to (...Rows.Count.4), so it adds the values to column D. I'm just looking in to how to add the source file name to column B when writing the first values (the second values are from the same source file).

Comment: Amended the code a little bit (my requirements slightly changed, so i'm only using a one cell range rather than a 5 cell range). I've added an additional step to paste in the file name: rDest.Resize(1, 1).Value = wbSource.FileName in column B but I think my interpritation of how it should work is slightly off.

Comment: Found it: rDest.Value = wbSource.Name. Worked a charm. Thanks for the great help again.

Comment: One last question: As the File names includes the name of the folder (vaFolder = ABC, and vaFile = ABC_Text_text.xls.) Is there anyway of 'iterating' through the vaFile using the vaFolder. So vaFiles = "_Text_text_xls" and then Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(sSourcePath & vaFolder(i) & "\" & vaFolder + vaFiles(i)). I can continue to paste in the full File name, but as I repeating the same thing over and ovre again I thought there could be a more VBA way. Just a thought.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Is there one file per folder or multiple? Are you copying a list of file names into the Array() function?  Where are those file names?  I think we should figure out how to go get those file names automatically.  Is it every file in that folder or only certain ones?  If it's every file in ABC, or even every xls file, there's a better way to do it.

Comment: What I've done for getting the SOURCE NAME seems to work great. It's taking the name of the soure file it's looping through at the time and putting it in Col B. next to the data in Col C & D.

Comment: One file in each folder. I've copied in the names of the FOLDERS in one ARRAY and the names of the FILES in another ARRAY. The FOLDER name is ABC. The FILE NAME in that folder is ABC_text_text.xls. My thought was that I could loop through the files by using a new vsFileName "_test_text.xls" and adding vaFOLDER at the start. It's probbaly quite comlicated - so what I have now works great, so I'll leave it at that. Again many thanks for this great piece of code.